# How can i make the following function work on right click only?

Tags: javascript

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);

      function getPosition(event)
      {
        var x = event.x;
        var y = event.y;

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

        x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
        y -= canvas.offsetTop;

        alert("x:" + x + " y:" + y);
      }
```

This simple function will get me the coordinates of where the mouse is clicked, it currently works on right and left click but i only want it to work if it's right click, some kind of `if rightClicked:`

Comment: I just wanted to know what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Nothing both answers are correct but i can only accept one and i upvoted yours :).

Comment: I was just wondering why same answer same time but different outcome altogether....thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`contextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu) event:

```js
canvas.addEventListener("contextmenu", getPosition, false);


function getPosition(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var x = event.x;
  var y = event.y;

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
  y -= canvas.offsetTop;

  console.log("x:" + x + " y:" + y);
  alert("x:" + x + " y:" + y);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: It works thanks, but i want to see the values not only in alert but in the console F12, i tried this `console.log("x is "+ x + "and y is "+y);` but it didn't work can you edit the answer to add that.

Comment: It did. The SO console.log() works after the alert is closed. Look at the real browser's console.

Answer (score 1):

The browser interprets the 'right click' as 'context menu'. Hence, your event handler needs to be bound to the `contextmenu` event.

Try:
`canvas.addEventListener("contextmenu", getPosition, false);`

```js
canvas.addEventListener("contextmenu", getPosition, false);

function getPosition(event){
  var x = event.x;
  var y = event.y;

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
  y -= canvas.offsetTop;

  alert("x:" + x + " y:" + y);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```